# Forgot Password But have SSH key access

Tags: passwd

I have SSH key access to my homelab ubuntu machine from my main computer and I didnt have to use the password for months. Now I am trying to access the machine from my laptop but I have forgotten the password. Is there a way to reset the password from my main computer while SSH'ed into it? I can not sudo due to this.

Or the only way is the physical way by mounting during boot?

Comment: Do you have access to Docker or something like that without having to use sudo?

Comment: Yes, i am running docker in that machine

Comment: Then you can do something like `docker run -it -v /etc:/etc ubuntu:$(lsb_release -sd)` to get a root shell in the container with access to your system's `/etc`, and then change the password to whatever you want

Comment: I get error: Unable to find image 'ubuntu:Ubuntu' locally

Comment: Update, i manually put 22.04 on the tag and i got root access. My next question would be, when I try passwd userFoo , i get passwd: Module is unknown
passwd: password unchanged

Comment: Last update, passwd worked after installing libpam-pwquality 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh yeah, it should have been `-sr` to get the version number as the tag using `lsb_release` and not `-sd`, my bad. Good to know you have fixed it. Since you needed to do additional things on top of my suggestion, consider posting an answer detailing exactly what you did.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get around this with docker, by using @muru's recommendation.

Gain root access:
`docker run -it -v /etc:/etc ubuntu:$(lsb_release -sr)`

Prerequisite package for passwd: `apt-get install -y libpam-pwquality`

Use passwd on the profile you are trying to change passwords: `passwd userFoo`

Comment: How did you install a package if you couldn't use sudo?